# Let $x,y,z$ are positive integers such that $x+y+z=200$. Find maximal value and minimal value of $M = x! + y! + z!$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations

> **Problem:** Let $x,y,z$ are positive integers such that $x+y+z=200$. Find maximal value and minimal value of $M = x! + y! + z!$

Could you give me some suggestion to solve this problem?

Comment: I'd suggest comparing $1! +1! +18!$ to $1! +2! + 17!$ to $1+9! + 10!$ to $6!+7!+7!$ and see if I can see any insight about whether $(n+a)! + (n-a)!$ is larger or smaller based on whether $n+a$ and $n-a$ are close or far apart.  And then I'd see if I could prove it.

Comment: is it $20$ (title) or $200$ (body)?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Oh, I forgot the title.

Answer (score 4):

Factorials grow very fast, so for a maximal value you want one of the numbers to be as large as possible.  For a minimal value you want the largest to be as small as possible.

Answer (score 0):

$n!-n$ is an non-decreasing sequence on $\mathbb{Z}_+$. That means that to maximize the given sum under the given conditions one should make the biggest value as big as possible and to minimize one should make it as small as possible. Thus the maximum is at $(x,y,z)=(1,1,18)$ with value $6402373705728002$ and minimum $(x,y,z)=(6,7,7)$ with value $10800$ (of course with permutations). I think you can fill in the details.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $x\ge y$. Then the effect on $x!+y!$ of increasing $x$ by $1$ and decreasing $y$ by $1$ is to increase the sum of the factorials by $xx!-(y-1)(y-1)!$.

Therefore the largest value is when two numbers are as small as possible i.e. $18!+1!+1!$.

For the minimum we require the numbers to be as close together as possible i.e $7!+7!+6!$.